# Custom Windows GINA authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, gina

In Windows, the GINA module can be extended to support different ways of authentication. For example, you can already see a support for Fingerprints, Smart Cards, or even Face Recognition (like what Lenovo did with their laptops).
What I am trying to achieve is not something as complex as those methods. All what I want is to be able to provide my custom authentication service (i.e My own authentication method at login).
Also, I want to know if there is a way to extend the default authentication method (password) so that there is a preprocessing stage of the password before sending it to the Windows Local Authentication Service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This MSDN Magazine articles may be able to answer your questions:

[Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

[Customizing GINA, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I know the question has been answered, but I couldn't help but notice that no mention was made of the replacement of GINA by Credential Providers.  Here are a couple links:

[Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

[ICredentialProvider Interface on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The new way will not work the same way as GINA did.

Answer (score 1):

additional information to above point:

Windows Vista and later versions of Microsoft Operating systems have replaced Gina with Credential provider's.

Tha