# Block Ctrl+Atl+Delete Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7

How to block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination on **Windows 7** with Delphi or anyway

Comment: You can check this... http://www.winvistaclub.com/t70.html

Comment: @Whiler That just controls what options Windows offers you when you press CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Comment: You don't Block Ctrl+Alt+Delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617303/does-windows-7-have-a-kiosk-mode

Comment: I haven't tried (and I don't plan to...). Does someone know what happens if all options are removed? (does it still display sth.?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934505/custom-windows-gina-authentication accepted answer may be works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. The [Secure Attention Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key) (the official Windows name for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>) is handled in kernel mode and it would be a humungous security hole if user mode apps were able to change what happens when the user sends the SAS.

Comment: I'm not sure about NT6 but in NT5 (Win2k, WinXP) there is nothing special about Ctrl+Alt+Del other than that it was registered as a global hotkey (via RegisterHotKey()) by the SAS window in winlogon.exe, which is a user-mode process. You could easily intercept it once you injected your code into that process.

Comment: Sure, when WinLogon still used GINA DLLs to process SAS notifications.  That went away in Windows Vista.